# Represent the similarity between many items in a nice manner MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, dataset, distance-matrix

I want to brainstorm an idea in MATLAB with you guys. Given a matrix with many columns (14K) and few rows (7) where columns are items and rows features of the items, I would like to compute the similarity with all items and keep it in matrix which is:

1. Easy to compute
2. Easy to access

for 1., I came up with a brilliant idea of using `pdist()` which is very fast:

```
 A % my matrix
 S = pdist(A')  % computes the similarity btw all columns very fast
```

However accessing `s` is not convenient. I prefer to access similarity between item `i` and `j` , e.g. using `S(i,j)`:

```
 S(4,5)  % is the similarity between item 4 and 5
```

In its original definition, `S` is an array not a matrix. Is making it as an 2D matrix a bad idea storage-wise? Could we think about a cool idea that can help me find which similaity corresponds to which items quickly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pdist2(A',A')`. What is returned is essentially the distance matrix in its standard form where element `(i,j)` is the dissimilarity (or similarity) between i-th and j-th pattern.
Also, if you want to use `pdist()`, which is ok, you can convert the resulting array into the well-known distance matrix by using the function `squareform()`.

So, in conclusion, if `A` is your dataset and `S` the distance matrix, you can use either

```
S=pdist(A');
S=squareform(S);
```

or

```
S=pdist2(A',A');
```

Now, regarding the storage point-of-view, you will certainly notice that such matrix is symmetric. What Matlab essentially proposes with the array `S` in `pdist()` is to save space: due to the fact that such matrix is symmetric you can as well save half of it in a vector. Indeed the array `S` has `m(m-1)/2` elements whereas the matrix form has `m^2` elements (if `m` is the number of patterns in your training set). On the other hand, most certainly is trickier to access such vector whereas the matrix is absolutely straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure to understand what your question is, but if you want to access `S(i, j)` easily then the function `squareform` is made for this:

```
S = squareform(pdist(A'));
```

Best,

Comment: Thank you both of the solutions work well. For now, for 14K items I am not facing memory problems but your comment is right Allessiox